# Search for a particular multiline pattern using awk and sed

Tags: sed, awk

I want to read from the file `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` and check for the below pattern that could span across multiple lines.

```
tags {
 hosttags = 1
}
```

There could be as many white spaces between `tags` and `{`, `{` and `hosttags` and so forth. Also `{` could follow `tags` on the next line instead of being on the same line with it.

I'm planning to use `awk` and `sed` to do this.

While reading the file `lvm.conf`, it should skip empty lines and comments.

That I'm doing using.

```
data=$(awk < cat `cat /etc/lvm/lvm.conf`            
/^#/        { next }                       
/^[[:space:]]*#/            { next }                
/^[[:space:]]*$/            { next }                
.          
.
```

How can I use `sed` to find the pattern I described above?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this

```
sed -n '/{/,/}/p' input
```

i.e. print lines between tokens (inclusive)?

To delete lines containing `#` and empty lines or lines containing only whitespace, use

```
sed -n '/{/,/}/p' input | sed '/#/d' | sed '/^[  ]*$/d'

                              space and a tab--^
```

**update**

If empty lines are just empty lines (no ws), the above can be shortened to

```
sed -e '/#/d' -e '/^$/d' input
```

**update2**

To check if the pattern `tags {...` is present in file, use

```
$ tr -d '\n' < input | grep -o 'tags\s*{[^}]*}'
tags { hosttags = 1# this is a comment}
```

The `tr` part above removes all newlines, i.e. makes everything into one single line (will work great if the file isn't to large) and then search for the `tags` pattern and outputs all matches.

The return code from grep will be `0` is pattern was found, `1` if not.
Return code is stored in variable `$?`. Or pipe the above to `wc -l` to get the number of matches found.

**update3**

regex for searcing for `tags { hosttags=1 }` with any number of ws anywhere

```
'tags\s*{\s*hosttags\s*=\s*1*[^}]*}'
```

Comment: it seems that op want to skip comments

Comment: This works great         sed '/#/d' | sed '/^[  ]*$/d'   .. But what I want is to search for the pattern .. Not just print it .. Also Please note that the pattern can have whitespaces in between ..

Comment: @user2161443 - you need a way to tell if `tags { ... }`are in the file?

Comment: @FredrikPihl .. Yes I want to check if the pattern tags { hosttage = 0 } is present in the lvm.conf file

Comment: @FredrikPihl, the updated command works. But it doesn't search for hosttags. I would need the entire thing tags { hostname = 1 } and the pattern can have many whitespaces in between .. I think 'tags\s*{[^}]*}'  needs some modification .. Please suggest

Comment: @user2161443 - glad I could help! don't forget to uppvote/accept when you have enough points. Itäs the best way to say thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this line:

```
 awk '/^\s*#|^\s*$/{next}1' /etc/lvm/lvm.conf
```

Comment: looks good but what about only displaying the pattern between the brackets?

Comment: @FredrikPihl why? without those info, one cannot understand the conf file. OP didn't ask for it either...

Comment: Yes. My main aim is to check if the pattern is present in lvm.conf file.

Comment: @FredrikPihl technical speaking, it could be done in two **dirty ways** (maybe more) ways. 1) dirty and quick A match `{` or `}` then `next` 2) dirty and quick B, let `RS` match `..{.. or ..}..`

Answer (score 0):

One could try preprocessing the file first, removing commments and empty lines and introducing empty lines behind the closing curly brace for easy processing with the second awk.

```
awk 'NF && $1!~/^#/{print; if(/}/) print x}' file | awk '/pattern/' RS=
```